# How can I render elements in v-for loop with different times?

Tags: vue.js, animation, v-for

Using the `v-for` loop, I want to show the elements of the array I looped at certain intervals. For example, the first element of the array I looped should be displayed after 100ms, the second element 200ms, and the third element 300ms later. How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found a way to accomplish what I want I hope this is helpful.

```js
const app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      itemArr: []
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    let items = [
      {
        title: "item1" 
      },
      {
        title: "item2"
      },
      {
        title: "item3"
      }
    ]
   
   items.forEach((item,index) => {
    setTimeout(()=>{
      this.itemArr.push(item)
    }, 100*(index+1))
   })
    
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>


<div id="app">
  <div class="main">
    <div class="fade-in-fwd" v-for="item in itemArr" :key="item.title">
      {{item.title}}
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<style>
  .main {
    display: flex;
    gap: 10px;
  }
  
  @-webkit-keyframes fade-in-fwd {
    0% {
      -webkit-transform: translateZ(-80px);
      transform: translateZ(-80px);
      opacity: 0;
    }
    100% {
      -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
      transform: translateZ(0);
      opacity: 1;
    }
  }
  
  @keyframes fade-in-fwd {
    0% {
      -webkit-transform: translateZ(-80px);
      transform: translateZ(-80px);
      opacity: 0;
    }
    100% {
      -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
      transform: translateZ(0);
      opacity: 1;
    }
  }
  
  .fade-in-fwd {
    -webkit-animation: fade-in-fwd 0.6s cubic-bezier(0.390, 0.575, 0.565, 1.000) both;
    animation: fade-in-fwd 0.6s cubic-bezier(0.390, 0.575, 0.565, 1.000) both;
  }
</style>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! How this answer is different from mine ? It also behaving in same way but my solution is optimized as we are passing time duration dynamically in setTimeout function.

Comment: Hello. The difference between your answer and my solution is due to the following; I did not want to change the value of the object element, but I wanted the elements of the array I looped to be created at certain intervals. This must have been understood as I couldn't explain my problem properly. And yes, the setTimeout function you wrote is a more optimized solution because it works dynamically. Thank you for your attention, I'll edit the description of my question exactly the way I want it to work.

Comment: In my answer also I am looping over an array elements only. In my answer `list` is an array.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that via using setTimeout and pass the timeout dynamically based on the index.

**Working Demo :**

```js
const app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      list: [{
        isFlag: false
      }, {
        isFlag: false
      }, {
        isFlag: false
      }]
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.list.forEach((obj, index) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
         obj.isFlag = true
      }, 100 * (index + 1));
    })
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <ul>
    <li v-for="(item, index) in list" :key="index">
      {{item.isFlag}}
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, that's not exactly what I wanted. Thanks anyway.

Comment: I answered as per your requirement only. I showed `How can I render elements in v-for loop with different times?`